# Is there a way to upload html pages into AEM DAM

Tags: html, aem, static-content, dam

We have bunch of help web pages(Static). We are just uploading to siteadmin using a third party tool. Is there a way to manage them in DAM?

Comment: Adding static Htmls into Dam and loading the pages from Dam location is not recommended and will have a performance issue of websites.

Comment: Thank you. Just to know is there a way to do that?

Comment: you can upload them as normal dam assets. but you need to handle certain configurations to render them as a html page. else it will download the file when you access as normal html binary data.

Answer (score 5):

I remember that in older versions of AEM < 6.1 the uploaded static html pages also can be rendered as normal cq pages when accessed by the uri with the content paths. But from AEM 6.1 onwards because of the security reasons this feature has been disabled(which required some Felix configuration modification to re-enable it).

> **Security concerns:**
>
> 1) There might be a chance of uploading a malicious files which can
>   damange the functionality of the website/system
>
> 2) Access these
>   uploaded files via content URL, might have a chance of files gets
>   executed in AEM (some sort of scripts execution) which can damage the
>   system/functionality. Etc.

**Just to give you some idea how we can add the static html  into AEM DAM**

i have the below static html (simplestaticpage.html) which is uploaded into DAM path `/content/dam/geometrixx-outdoors/simplebanner/` but when i access it via the content path url `http://localhost:4502/content/dam/geometrixx-outdoors/simplebanner/simplestaticpage.html` it will download as binary because of the default behaviour of the AEM DAM content Disposition 
restrictions.

To enable the DAM static pages to render as normal cq:pages you need to remove the **text/html** mime types from  **Dam Safe Binary Filter(com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.servlet.DamContentDispositionFilter)** as shown below.

[image: dam safe filter]

After removal of this mime type from configuration, when i access the url `http://localhost:4502/content/dam/geometrixx-outdoors/simplebanner/simplestaticpage.html` the page renders fine.
[image: Static page from DAM]

> Note: Also remember if this doesn't work you might require to add
>   ***Content Disposition Paths*** the in **Apache Sling Content Disposition Filter**

~ Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your answer. Helps.

Comment: On my 6.4 environment, setting configurations of Dam Safe Binary & Apache Sling Content Disposition Filter is not working (but it does work on 6.3)

Answer (score 0):

AEM Design importer does uploads html pages. You can create your own HTML pages independently and use it within your application.

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/administer/personalization/campaigns/extending-the-design-importer-for-landingpages.html